# Excel VBA creating a new Outlook appointment results in a cancelled appointment

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, meeting-request

When I run the following code with .display, the Outlook Appointment gets created in the correct way (shared calendar, recipients, time etc) and I can send the resultant meeting request and it is received by the recipient as a meeting request. However, if I change .display to .send, everything appears to work OK, but the recipient recieves a meeting cancellation (for a meeting that doesn't exist!).

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

```
Sub CreateMeetings()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olAppItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim r As Long
Dim oApp As Object
Dim oNameSpace As Namespace
Dim myCalendar As Object
Dim OLNS As Object
Const olAppointmentItem As Long = 1
Dim OLAppointment As Object
Dim MeetingKey As String
Dim datenum As Long
Dim smtprecipient As String
Dim MeetingKeyString As String
Dim emailchk As Long



Set oApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error Resume Next


Set olApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If olApp Is Nothing Then
On Error Resume Next
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If olApp Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Outlook is not available!"
Exit Sub
End If
End If
'get default user email address
smtprecipient = GetSMTPEmailAddress

'check to see if email address returned is a valid one
emailchk = InStr(1, smtprecipient, "@company_domain.co.uk")
'get a valid email address if the check fails
If emailchk = 0 Then
    smtprecipient = InputBox("Enter your Company Email Address", "Email Address Required")
End If


Set OLNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    OLNS.Logon
    Dim objRec As Outlook.Recipient
    Set objRec = OLNS.CreateRecipient(smtprecipient)
    objRec.Resolve
    Set myCalendar = OLNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRec, olFolderCalendar).Folders("Frontline")
    Set OLAppointment = myCalendar.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
    Dim i As Long, Schedsht As Worksheet
    Set Schedsht = Worksheets("Shift Allocation")
    Sheets("Shift Allocation").Select

For i = 6 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Schedsht.Range("T" & i).Value = "" And Schedsht.Range("S" & i).Value = True Then
datenum = Date + (Time * 10000) + i
MeetingKeyString = Schedsht.Range("Z" & i).Value
MeetingKey = "S" & CStr(datenum) & Schedsht.Range("B" & i).Value
    With OLAppointment
            .Subject = "Shift" & " (" & MeetingKey & ")"
            .RequiredAttendees = Schedsht.Range("I" & i).Value & ";" & Schedsht.Range("J" & i).Value _
             & ";" & Schedsht.Range("K" & i).Value
            .Start = Schedsht.Range("D" & i).Value
            .End = Schedsht.Range("E" & i).Value
            .Location = Schedsht.Range("C" & i).Value
            .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 720
            .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
            
            .Body = Schedsht.Range("M" & i).Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Welcome to our new Rota system. For details on how this all works, _
            please go to xxxx."
           .Display
            '.Send
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

Schedsht.Range("T" & i).Value = True
Schedsht.Range("Y" & i).Value = MeetingKey
Schedsht.Range("AA" & i).Value = MeetingKeyString
Else

End If

Next i
 
MsgBox "All Shifts Processed"
Set olAppItem = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
Set oFolder = Nothing

Exit Sub

Set olAppItem = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

See above. changing to .display works OK, .send doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not send items from a shared folder explicitly because an incorrect sender will be used. You can use the [SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname) property for mail items, but not appointments, when you need to send items on behalf of another person.

Call the `Save` method before the `Send` one to submit the item from a shared folder.

Comment: Thanks for the information Eugene - that sort of makes it an issue for me. Any ideas how I can have several users create calendar apointments like this?

Comment: Does the `Display` method does exactly what you are expecting?

Comment: yes it does. it creates a meeting request and if the "send" button is pressed, the invite goes to the recipients as a new meeting request and gets entered into the shared calebdar as expected

Comment: A wild thought - have you tried calling `Save` prior to calling the `Send` method?

Comment: You absolute legend! I love simple answers that work! I don't know why, but that appears to have done the trick Thanks!